# Why every time f5(refresh) is my website insert data to the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that inserts data into the database using mysql. When I click submit (add data) the data is inserted into the database successfully. However, when I press f5 (refresh), the data is still inserted into the database. I do not know where I'm wrong. Please help me. This is my code:

```
<?php
$username = "user_tintuc"; // Khai báo username
$password = "123456";      // Khai báo password
$server   = "localhost";   // Khai báo server
$dbname   = "tintuc";      // Khai báo database

// Kết nối database tintuc
$connect = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $dbname);

//Nếu kết nối bị lỗi thì xuất báo lỗi và thoát.
if ($connect->connect_error) {
    die("Không kết nối :" . $conn->connect_error);
    exit();
}

//Khai báo giá trị ban đầu, nếu không có thì khi chưa submit câu lệnh insert sẽ báo lỗi
$title = "";
$date = "";
$description = "";
$content = "";

//Lấy giá trị POST từ form vừa submit
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if(isset($_POST["title"])) { $title = $_POST['title']; }
    if(isset($_POST["date"])) { $date = $_POST['date']; }
    if(isset($_POST["description"])) { $description = $_POST['description']; }
    if(isset($_POST["content"])) { $content = $_POST['content']; }

    //Code xử lý, insert dữ liệu vào table
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tin_xahoi (title, date, description, content)
    VALUES ('$title', '$date', '$description', '$content')";

    if ($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Thêm dữ liệu thành công";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connect->error;
    }
}
//Đóng database
$connect->close();
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Tiêu đề:</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="title" value=""></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>Ngày tháng:</th>
            <td><input type="date" name="date" value=""></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>Mô tả:</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="description" value=""></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>Nội dung:</th>
            <td><textarea cols="30" rows="7" name="content"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="submit">Gửi</button>
</form>
```

I edited it like this. But it's still like that.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST["date"])) { $date = $_POST['date'];}
    if(isset($_POST["MAB"])) { $MAB = $_POST['MAB']; }
    if(isset($_POST["MBA"])) { $MBA = $_POST['MBA']; }
    if(isset($_POST["PAB"])) { $PAB = $_POST['PAB']; }
    if(isset($_POST["PBA"])) { $PBA = $_POST['PBA']; }

$sql = "INSERT INTO `dbsht` (`date`, `MAB`, `MBA`, `PAB`, `PBA`) VALUES ('$date', '$MAB', '$MBA', '$PAB', '$PBA')"; 
    if ($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Thêm dữ liệu thành công";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connect->error;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do `POST` check before inserting data. `if($_POST){//your_stuffs}`

Comment: One of the solution to this problem is a pattern commonly known as [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Comment: One more thing is whenever you press `CTRL+R` or `F5` then your browser will re-post your form and your condition will be true and data has insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal issues. You should use POST-Redirect-GET pattern to prevent it. After insert database successful, you should response with redirect to GET request.

You may try

```
    if ($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        $_SESSION["ADD_SUCCESS"] = 1;

        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connect->error;
    }
```

For successful message

```
    //Đóng database
    $connect->close();

    if(isset($_SESSION["ADD_SUCCESS"])) 
    { 
        echo "Chúc mừng bạn đã thêm dữ liệu thành công";

        unset($_SESSION["ADD_SUCCESS"]); 
    }
```

Comment: @hungtrinh Please using english or SO moderator will downvote or make a penalty for you

Comment: I have another problem with changing the url in the iframe tag. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it, but don't, reorganize it and rewrite it because your approach is border-line terrible. 
Have myform.html as one file, your php code for inserting data in db as another file like db_insert.php and your data for db connection (user, pass, db, host) in separate file OUTSIDE of public folder (outside public_html or whatever) in file config.inc.php, for example. Do this and you'll avoid this problem that you have right now and many others.

So in **myform.html** enter data and submit => **db_insert.php** gets data from myform.html, fetches data from **config.inc.php**, enters it in DB and redirects back to myform.html or some other part of your application.

After you make it work and figure it out how and why, then read a few articles about AJAX and how to do the same job without leaving your form page. It's obvious that you just started learning, so make sure you learn it the right way ;)

Comment: Thanks for your advice :). @Bozidar Sikanjic

Answer (score 0):

Once the POST request has been sent the php code should do the necessary logic tests and sanitation routines on the data, construct and execute the sql and finally redirect to either the same page or another. The redirect will prevent the form being re-submitted when refreshing the page

```
<?php

    $message='';

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        try{

            $username = "user_tintuc";
            $password = "123456";
            $server   = "localhost";
            $dbname   = "tintuc";   
            $connect = new mysqli( $server, $username, $password, $dbname );

            $title = isset( $_POST["title"] ) ? $_POST["title"] : false;
            $date = isset( $_POST["date"] ) ? $_POST["date"] : false;
            $description = isset( $_POST["description"] ) ? $_POST["description"] : false;
            $content = isset( $_POST["content"] ) ? $_POST["content"] : false;

            if( $title && $date && $description && $content ){

                $sql = 'insert into `tin_xahoi` ( `title`, `date`, `description`, `content`) values (?,?,?,?)';
                $stmt=$connect->prepare( $sql );

                if( $stmt ){

                    $stmt->bind_param('ssss',$title,$date,$description,$content);
                    $result=$stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->close();

                    /* set a temporary session variable - used to display message */
                    $_SESSION['dbstatus']=$result ? 'Record added' : 'Sorry - an error occurred';

                    header('Location: ?status=' . ( $result ? 'ok' : 'error' ) );

                } else {
                    throw new Exception('Failed to prepare sql');
                }
            } else {
                throw new Exception('one or more variables are empty');
            }
        }catch( Exception $e ){
            $message=sprintf('<p>%s</p>',$e->getMessage());
        }
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Tiêu d?:</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="title" value=""></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th>Ngày tháng:</th>
                    <td><input type="date" name="date" value=""></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th>Mô t?:</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="description" value=""></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th>N?i dung:</th>
                    <td><textarea cols="30" rows="7" name="content"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button type="submit">G?i</button>
            <?php

                /* Display the message from session variable and unset the variable */
                if( !empty( $_GET['status'] ) && isset( $_SESSION['dbstatus'] ) ) {
                    $message=$_SESSION['dbstatus'];
                    unset( $_SESSION['dbstatus'] );
                }

                /* Display whatever is in $message */
                echo $message;

            ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```